# How can I convert ESlint erros into warnings

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, eslintrc

```js
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "projects/**/*"
  ],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [
        "*.ts"
      ],
      "parserOptions": {
        "project": [
          "tsconfig.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "createDefaultProgram": true
      },
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
      ],
      "rules": {
        "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "element",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "kebab-case"
          }
        ],
        "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
          "error",
          {
            "type": "attribute",
            "prefix": "app",
            "style": "camelCase"
          }
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/dot-notation": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": [
          "off",
          {
            "accessibility": "explicit"
          }
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "error",
        "brace-style": [
          "error",
          "1tbs"
        ],
        "id-blacklist": "off",
        "id-match": "off",
        "max-len": "off",
        "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
        "valid-typeof": "error"
      }
    },
    {
      "files": [
        "*.html"
      ],
      "extends": [
        "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/recommended"
      ],
      "rules": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I have installed angular ESlint in my project. Earlier with Tslint I was able to view all the linting errors as Warning (in yellow color), but now after replacing the deprecated TSLint with the ESLint all the warnings are now being displayed in red color. These errors of lint which are displayed in red color will hide the actual errors of programming which were easily noticeable earlier because TSLint's error were in yellow color and actual errors were in red color. Now all the errors and warnings are in red color.
Please help me to show lint errors in yellow color as warning.
Please find attached the image where you can see my whole file in red color because of the warnings are now being displayed in red instead of yellow color.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHrMv.png)
My angular version is 8.2.0

I tried replacing error by warn in eslintrc.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Update your rules in ESlint to "warn" instead of "error" to get warnings only.

```
      "rules": {
    "@angular-eslint/component-selector": [
      "warn",
      {
        "type": "element",
        "prefix": "app",
        "style": "kebab-case"
      }
    ],
    "@angular-eslint/directive-selector": [
      "warn",
      {
        "type": "attribute",
        "prefix": "app",
        "style": "camelCase"
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/dot-notation": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": [
      "off",
      {
        "accessibility": "explicit"
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "warn",
    "brace-style": [
      "warn",
      "1tbs"
    ],
    "id-blacklist": "off",
    "id-match": "off",
    "max-len": "off",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
    "valid-typeof": "warn"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Did u write some extra rules for your eslint and if u did, then can u please share it with me? @Ritik Banger

Comment: @T.B.-TantiyaBichchu There are several Eslint rules and should be used as per code quality and development preference.

Comment: Can u har those several rules or drop a link here where I can navigate and find or select some rules according to my needs?

Comment: @T.B.-TantiyaBichchu https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/